# Paradox of a unit 2 height cylinder

Tags: volume

The surface area of a cylinder of height 2 units is $2\pi r^2 + 2\pi rh,$ which is greater than its volume $V = \pi r^2h=2\pi r^2$. Am I missing something? This is so weird!

Comment: No paradox. Volume and area are measured in different units.

Comment: There is no rule that the surface area must be less than the volume.

Comment: The surface area of a unit cube is $6$, while its volume is $1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that the surface area must be less than the volume. They are totally different units.

Consider the unit cube with sides of length $1\, m$. The volume is $1 \, m^3$ but the surface area is $6 \, m^2$.

The same holds in two dimensions, a unit square with sides of length $1\, m$ has a perimeter of $4\,m$ and an area of $1\, m^2$.

To make things even more weird, there are objects with infinite surface area but finite volume, for example [Gabriel's horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn).

Comment: Oh yeah.thank you for pointing it out amd m47145 and bakula!